# Dinamic array don't allocate the same numbers of elements than stack array

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an array of 18 elements of BYTE whit calloc but don't know why calloc only give me back only 8 elements, I did it manually in the stack and the program works.

```
int arrsize;
BYTE copyrow[18];
arrsize = sizeof(copyrow);
```

When i compile here arrsize = to 18, so, evrething is fine.
But when I use calloc:

```
int arrsize;
BYTE *copyrow;
copyrow = calloc(18, sizeof(BYTE));
arrsize = sizeof(copyrow);
```

Now the compiler say arrsize = to 8, so I don't know what's happening here. Need help.

Comment: 8 is the pointer size. You should store the number of elements in the array in separate variable. Compiler can't get size of array where your pointer `copyrow` points.

Comment: @machine_1 I flagged it as well and SO added this comment :(

Answer (score 3):

When you define `BYTE *copyrow;`, `copyrow` is a pointer, and the size of a pointer is `8` on a 64 bit architecture, regardless how "big" the memory block to which it points is.

`BYTE copyrow[18];`, in constrast, is an array of 18 `BYTE`-elements, and the size of such an array is `18 * sizeof(BYTE)`.

You could do it this way:

```
int nrOfElements = 18;  // could be dynamically set as well.
BYTE *copyrow = calloc(nrOfElements, sizeof(BYTE));
int arrsize = sizeof(BYTE) * nrOfElements;
```

Comment: I just want to create an array wich number of elements dinamiclly, in the example i'm trying I know is 18 numbers of elements, but that will change for other examples.

Comment: @ManKino the answer tells you exactly what you are asking. Instead of writing `int nrOfElements = 18;` you calculate the number by any means necessary to your algorithm.

Comment: Ok so if BYTE copyrow[18]; is the same as BYTE *copyrow = calloc(18, sizeof(BYTE)); and I know that, why my program doesn't work with the dinamic one. This array is not storing the 18 bytes of data in need, or as I can't see what is storing each element of the dinamic array, I don't know what really is storing each element.

Comment: I didn't find a way to see in the debugger what are storing each element of the dinamic array

Answer (score 1):

**Array and pointer are different things.**

In many cases array will decay to a pointer, but they are essentially different.

```
BYTE copyrow[18];
arrsize = sizeof(copyrow);
```

Here `sizeof` shows the size of the whole array, which is `18 * sizeof(BYTE)`.

```
BYTE *copyrow;
arrsize = sizeof(copyrow);
```

Here `sizeof` shows the size of a pointer, which has nothing to do with what it points to.

Comment: so if the size of une element is 8, half of the problem is going good, but anyway I need to allocate dinamic memory for an array of element, that, in this example I know is 18 but that can change, the thin is, when I declare the array in the stack, the program works, but I need to do it dinamic.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this was also a confusing topic when I started of with C. It seemed like `sizeof()` were implemented differently depending on what the argument was.

`sizeof()` is in most cases evaluated at compile time and the only reason `int a[n]; sizeof(a);` works is because all the information needed to figure out its size is present at compile time.

```
BYTE copyrow[18];
arrsize = sizeof(copyrow);
```

Is (as pointed out by others) interpreted as...

```
BYTE copyrow[18];
arrsize = sizeof(BYTE)*18;
```

...by the compiler. Hence the dynamic case would look the same:

```
BYTE *copyrow;
copyrow = (BYTE*) calloc(18, sizeof(BYTE));
arrsize = sizeof(BYTE)*18;
```